# Binding a DataGrid to a Queue is showing empty

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm probably doing something trivially wrong here but I can't seem to get the following to work:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
    }

    public Queue<Player> quePlayers { get; set; }

    Random rand = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

    public void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        quePlayers = new Queue<Player>();
        //quePlayers.Add(new Player() { FullName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Age = rand.Next() % 40, SomeData = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });
        //quePlayers.Add(new Player() { FullName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Age = rand.Next() % 40, SomeData = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });
        //quePlayers.Add(new Player() { FullName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Age = rand.Next() % 40, SomeData = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });
        //quePlayers.Add(new Player() { FullName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Age = rand.Next() % 40, SomeData = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });
        //quePlayers.Add(new Player() { FullName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Age = rand.Next() % 40, SomeData = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });

        quePlayers.Enqueue(new Player() { FullName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Age = rand.Next() % 40, SomeData = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });
        quePlayers.Enqueue(new Player() { FullName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Age = rand.Next() % 40, SomeData = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });
        quePlayers.Enqueue(new Player() { FullName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Age = rand.Next() % 40, SomeData = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });
        quePlayers.Enqueue(new Player() { FullName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Age = rand.Next() % 40, SomeData = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });
        quePlayers.Enqueue(new Player() { FullName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Age = rand.Next() % 40, SomeData = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });

        dgTest.ItemsSource = quePlayers;
        //dgTest.ItemsSource = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dgTest.ItemsSource);

    }
```

If I change that Queue to a List the grid will have data appear in it but Queue and Stack will not cooperate

The dgTest.Items property has 5 members, and the CollectionView I get back is EnumerableCollectionView, which I can enumerate over and see the 5 members within

My XAML is trivial too

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgTest" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

Any idea what's wrong? Queue implements IEnumerable and the only requirement for ItemsSource is IEnumerable

Comment: My guess is the AutoGenerateColumns.  Try manually setting one column.

Comment: That fixed it thanks. Looks like it's a known bug https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/538210/wpf-datagrid-with-autogeneratecolumns-shows-nothing
Please set an Answer so I can give you credit and close the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is the AutoGenerateColumns. Try manually setting one column.